# pulling data from CDP (cloudera data platform) using hive query language (HQL) into python

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera

I am pulling some data from CDP using hive query language HQL into python. One of the columns gives me below output. In hive datatype of that column seems to be `array`

I wouldn't like to perform any data processing in python as it will be slow

what are those `b''` and how could I get rid of them while not adding any spacing between numbers

```
0                          b'[1152]'
1    b'[1600,128,192,128,0,384,256]'
2                          b'[2752]'
3                       b'[384,192]'
4                      b'[1152,448]'
```

The output that i want is

```
    0                          [1152]
    1    [1600,128,192,128,0,384,256]
    2                          [2752]
    3                       [384,192]
    4                      [1152,448]
```

Comment: what is the data type ? is it string? if yes, you can easily do `substring(col,2)` and remove it

Comment: i am pulling it in python and it shows as `object`. and in hive datatype seems to be `array`